# Открытие ссылок из WebView в установленном приложении - Android, Java

Tags: java, android, webview

При нажатии открыть в Google Play ничего не происходит! Также как и с ссылками, например https://m.vk.com не переадресовывает в установленное приложение ВКонтакте

Кусок кода:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if( URLUtil.isNetworkUrl(url) ) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (appInstalledOrNot(url)) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity( intent );
                } else {

                }
                return true;
            }

            private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri) {
                PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
                try {
                    pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
                    return true;
                } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                }

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }

        });
```

UPD: Я гуглил много раз, подходящего ответа так и не нашёл
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Наверняка вы назначили `WebViewClient`, чтобы каждый клик по странице не перекидывал в браузер. Теперь вы должны переопределить метод [`shouldOverrideUrlLoading`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)) и его новую версию. Внутри метода проверять url и по условию создавать и отправлять интент на открытие этого адреса в систему. Пример можно посмотреть в гайде: https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#HandlingNavigation

Comment: @woesss суть была в том что это браузер. И не все ссылки должны открываться в сторонних браузерах. А только те, которые можно открыть в установленном приложении. Сейчас подправлю вопрос (добавлю кусок кода), посмотрите и скажите в чём ошибка

Comment: `https://m.vk.com` - сразу откроется внутри на проверке `if(URLUtil.isNetworkUrl(url) )`, если реализация соответствует имени. `getPackageInfo` принимает первым параметром не uri, а packageName - он же applicationId. Чтобы узнать есть ли в системе приложения, способные открыть uri нужно можно использовать [PackageManager.queryIntentActivities(...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities(android.content.Intent,%20int)).

Comment: Но для мобильных клиентов, открывающих интернет-адреса придётся зашивать в приложение список их имён пакетов и проверять наличие клиента соответствующего адресу по packageName методом `getPackageInfo`, или искать такой пакет в списке, который вернёт `queryIntentActivities` а после запускать или открывать в себя.